# Basic question on executing multiple commands in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

I have the following on my code:

```
  where
    launch :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Text)
    launch = do
        line <- launchLine
        return $ lineToText <$> line

    launchLine :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Line)
    launchLine = fold (inproc "juke" ["launch", "--profile", "jukeplay", pack baseImage] mempty) $
        Fold selectLaunchName Nothing id
```

The lines above work fine. My problem (and question) is that I want to execute another command before this launch line, so it could be something like:

```
  where
    launch :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Text)
    launch = do
        line <- launchLine
        return $ lineToText <$> line

    launchLine :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Line)
    launchLine = fold (inproc "juke" ["image", "copy", "jukebox:" <> pack baseImage, "local:", "--copy-aliases"] mempty) $
        Fold selectLaunchName Nothing id

    launchLine :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Line)
    launchLine = fold (inproc "juke" ["launch", "--profile", "jukeplay", pack baseImage] mempty) $
        Fold selectLaunchName Nothing id
```

This obviously does not work. How could I accomplish this?

I need to have this "juke image copy" done before the "juke launch.." is executed

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What do you want to do with the output of `juke image copy ...`?

Comment: Nothing really. This is a shell command that should be executed prior to the second command. The output in this case wont be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine monadic actions with `(>>)`:

```
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

Or with `do` syntax, which desugars to `(>>)`:

```
\act1 act2 -> do {act1; act2} :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

For example:

```
launch :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Text)
launch = do
    preLaunchLine
    line <- launchLine
    return $ lineToText <$> line

preLaunchLine :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Line)
preLaunchLine = fold (inproc "juke" ["image", "copy", "jukebox:" <> pack baseImage, "local:", "--copy-aliases"] mempty) $
    Fold selectLaunchName Nothing id

launchLine :: MonadIO m => m (Maybe Line)
launchLine = fold (inproc "juke" ["launch", "--profile", "jukeplay", pack baseImage] mempty) $
    Fold selectLaunchName Nothing id
```

Comment: we don't know if he wants to ignore the intermediate result though

Comment: @JorgeAdriano Sure we do. In the comments, they say "The output [of `juke image copy ...`] in this case wont be used".

Comment: @DanielWagner oh I hadn't seen his answer yet, my bad!

Comment: @user1858059 you should follow the suggestion in the warning (or use the `void` function if you prefer)